# Jint+JSfuck - 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'

Tags: javascript, c#, deobfuscation, jint

I'm trying to run the following code in jint:

```
Jint.Engine engine = new Jint.Engine();
var result = engine.SetValue("data", data).Execute("(/\\n(.+)/.exec(eval(data.replace(/\\s+/, \"\").slice(0, -2)))[1]);").GetCompletionValue();
```

Which, when unescaped, is executing the following javascript:

```
(/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(data.replace(/\s+/, "").slice(0, -2)))[1]);
```

the `data` variable corresponds to a JSfuck string, similar to this: https://pastebin.com/vmGAebW5

The problem is that I always get a 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' exception, even though the javascript works fine when run in a browser. Any ideas as to what is causing the issue?

Comment: Does the deobfuscated version work?

Comment: I would highly suggest you change your string declaration to have the @ infront of it, especially with this magnitude of escape characters. It makes your string unreadable... Example: `.Execute(@"your-escaped-string-here");`

Comment: @Ryan I don't have access to the deobfuscated version, but I assume it must, as the following tool can deobfuscate it: https://enkhee-osiris.github.io/Decoder-JSFuck/

Comment: @user2950509: Deobfuscate it using that tool and try it…

Comment: @Ryan I need to be able to deobfuscate it with jint, not that online tool. I know it works.

Comment: This is a debugging step. To be clear: deobfuscate it using that tool and run it in Jint. Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0):

`windows.location` is not available in Jint as the `window` object is provided by the browser. If you wanted to be able to run this kind of code then you would need to mock all the browser exposed objects, which is a huge task.

Also you are using `SetValue('window.location', "")` which I assume is not a valid call. The property name should not contain dots.

Comment: Forgetting that, how could I figure out what's causing the 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' ?